# Is there a more formal word for 'ratting'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a more formal term used to describe ***ratting***:

> A verb intransitive identified as slang meaning to betray one's
>   comrade by giving information on a friend to the authorities.

Specifically, I want to know what word would appear in a court document? Should "*ratting*" be included in criminal proceedings?

**Is there any formal word I can use for 'ratting'?**

Comment: Please say where you found your definition

Comment: My definition is an amalgamation of answers from Yahoo Answers and Google search results, as it is a slang word not found in dictionaries.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "court documents", but it's unlikely anything like that would need to use such "loaded" terms (informal *rat, grass, finger*, formal *betray, expose*, etc.). But it's General Reference that ***ratting*** is slang, and that ***betrayal*** (as implied by OP's cited definition) is a "formal" alternative.

Comment: What I mean by 'court documents', is if ratting were illegal and specified in the criminal code - what word would it appear as. Betrayal is a good one, and may be the best one - but ratting is more specific to betraying a friend by 'telling on him'. Betrayal can mean many more things.

Comment: Try a thesaurus: denounce,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have got to the stage of court documents, it may have reached the point where the informant has *[turned Queen's Evidence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/queen%27s%20evidence)*

> 1. (English law) (when the sovereign is female) evidence given for the Crown against his or her former associates in crime by an
>    accomplice (esp in the phrase *turn queen's evidence*) Also called (when
>    the sovereign is male) *king's evidence*. US equivalent *state's evidence* [Collins English Dictionary via Dictionary.com]

but that would only be the case if criminal proceedings where in hand.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK at least, police call associates of criminals who report things to the police *informants*. So the action would be *informing*. From [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inform?q=informing):

> Give incriminating information about someone to the police or other authority

Answer (score 0):

I've found the best alternative to *ratting* someone out is the word *denounce*.

Denounce, according to [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/denounce), means to formally accuse someone of wrongdoing, or condemn them as reprehensible.

> He denounced the man in open court, and the court motioned to convict.

Comment: I wouldn't use this one, as *ratting* is a secretive thing, where as *denouncing* tends to be public.